# CSS not working when page has multiple query strings

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

A customer originally had this issue in an IE browser (I'm not sure what version). I was able to replicate it on my Chrome browser on my Samsung Galaxy 3 mobile. When viewing this link with two query string, the CSS is not used on the page:
    http://catalogs.infocommiq.com/avcat/ctl1642/index.cfm?bimlist&company=203603

You can view the source code for the page and see that the CSS files are being called and are available. 
    iqRegional.css
    keywordsearchsearchform.css
    iqBIM.css

One CSS file is called with an absolute link, the other two with relative links. All files will not load on my Chrome browser on my Samsung Galaxy 3 mobile for this page.

However, if I shorten the query string in the link, the CSS loads fine.
    http://catalogs.infocommiq.com/avcat/ctl1642/index.cfm?bimlist

Answer (score 1):

For http://catalogs.infocommiq.com/avcat/ctl1642/index.cfm

Lines 67-72 have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    MyIQDynamicListArrayName = 'MyIQListArrays', List_Catalog_ID = 1642; 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://catalogs.infocommiq.com/avcat/css/iqRegional.css?v=6"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../keywordsearchsearchform.css?v=6"><title>Audio Visual Equipment, AV Service Providers Directory and Resource Center - AV-iQ</title><meta name="description" content="The most complete audio visual equipment, AV service providers directory and industry resource center including AV equipment, installations, dealers, rentals, service providers, case studies, news and more!"><meta name="keywords" content="audio visual equipment AV services providers directory resource installations dealers rentals 3D cameras displays projectors screens mounts video production presentation systems content delivery digital signage test measurement signal management furniture consoles media manufacturers  - AV-iQ"></head>

<body>
```

In comparison, for http://catalogs.infocommiq.com/avcat/ctl1642/index.cfm?bimlist&company=203603

Lines 62-67 have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            MyIQDynamicListArrayName = 'MyIQListArrays', List_Catalog_ID = 1642; 
        </script>
        </head>

<body>
```

So, there are many more css files being called in the first link. You'll want to check your template code to see why add a query string kills the calls to those css files.